# How to Install PHP 7.0.2 in My CentOS 7 Linod

Tags: php, centos7, linode

I want to Install Supported PHP Version for Magento 2.1.x the Magento 2.1.x technology stack requirements is either PHP 5.6.5–5.6.x, 7.0.2, 7.0.4 or 7.0.6–7.0.x.

I tried with below command

```
# rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
# yum install php70w
# # yum --enablerepo=remi-php70 install php70
```

Its installed PHP 7.0.31 which is not supported by Magento 2.1.x.

1. Please suggest the correct command for PHP 7.0.2
2. How to un-install PHP 7.0.31 from Cent OS 7 and Install PHP 7.0.2

Please do let me know how to downgrade from PHP 7.0.31 to PHP 7.0.2 in Cent OS

Comment: try this to remove : sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common

Comment: voted to close this, because it is off-topic here. while `7.0.31` == `7.0.x`.

Comment: Don't know but 7.0.3 is not working and its clearly mentioned in guideline by Magneto 

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html